# How to change a class of edges to a list in NetworkX?

Tags: python, list, class, networkx, edges

I tried to create a list from the class of edges in NetworkX using the function  `list()`. However, when I access the list using `print(data[0])`, I get the edge and all its attributes but I only want the edge. How can I access the edge alone?

```
edges = g.edges()
print("Type = " ,type(edges))
      
print("All edges: ", edges )

#Changing the class of edges into a list
data = list(edges. items())

print("First edge = ", data[0])
```

This is the output of the code:
[image]

Comment: What is `services`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! I initially defined it as services instead of edges. I edited the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `items`:

```
edges = list(g.edges())
print(edges)

# Output
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (0, 8),
 (0, 10),
 ...]
```

`items` return the edges and the associated data.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I am new to python and networkX and this was very helpful!